# DBContext in Class Library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have several solutions that includes an Database builder project. It reads a number of script files and creates tables, views, loads data and so on.

Having a project copy in every solution where I need this seems unecessary, so I started to move the code to a class library instead, having the necessary script files at AppSettings.

Everything seems to work fine, until I run a project that uses this new class library. I get an exception when I try to run the first Database.SqlQuery. Checking the dbContext connectionstring it seems ok.

DatabaseBuilder - Console Application with reference to Class Library

App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Script_Startup" value="Scripts/OnStartup.txt"/>
    <add key="Script_Tables" value="Scripts/Tables.txt"/>
    <add key="Script_Views" value="Scripts/Views.txt"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBModelEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.Model.csdl|res://*/Model.Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=TEST_DATABASE;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Class Library - App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

This part shows how the dbContext is created. I've checked the _model data and it is connected to the database.

```
//Class Library - Method for creating dbConext
    internal SchemaUpgrade()
    {
      _model = new DbContext("DBModelEntities");
    }

//Class Library - Method for checking if Table exists
    private bool TableExists(string tableName)
    {
      const string template = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES " +
                              "WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = '{0}') " +
                              "SELECT 1 AS TABLE_EXISTS ELSE SELECT 0 AS TABLE_EXISTS;";

      var i = _model.Database.SqlQuery<int>(string.Format(template, tableName));
      return i.First() == 1;
    }
```

The Database.SqlQuery throws an exception with the following message:

Unable to load the specified metadata resource.

The difference between the Class Library and the old method having a project in every solution is that the model is now not part of the Class Library solution.

So I'm guessing that it might be related to the DbContext is now not used in a partial class where the various entities (`public DBSet<TableName> TableName {get;set;}` is defined.

Is it not possible to use DbContext in a class library? The reason why I try to do this is that the table schema is different from solution to solution, so I'd like the Class Library not to worry about which tables might exists or not.

Just run the database update scripts and create database objects

Here's a photo which shows how the project in one solution references the class library
[image]

Update:
I believe the issue to be that the class library does not find the model

```
"metadata=res://*/Model.Model.csdl|res://*/Model.Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Checking the connectionstring in debug, everything looks fine

Answer (score 0):

Of Course it is possible to use DBContect in a class library, this is what I am currently doing in my projects, I just point them to the DLL(class library)

I suspect your app.config file is missing the connection string in the class library project.

add it , it should be the same:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBModelEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.Model.csdl|res://*/Model.Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=TEST_DATABASE;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Don't forget to recompile to see the changes.

Comment: You are correct. The connectionstring is missing from the class library app.config. But that was left out on purpose.. The class library should not "know" of the actual connectionstring, but get this from the project which uses the class library dll..  Or am I missing something here? How may the class library then be used towards different databases?

Comment: If you have different database you will use different connection string, any project of your solution will need the connection string if it is using the DLL

Comment: I've added the connectionstring to the Class Library, but it still fails. I think we might misunderstand how my two solutions are set up, so I've added a new photo which shows how they are related

Answer (score 0):

I did not need the connectionstring in the Class Library. 
The issue was related to the name of the model.

The config file for the project that holds the model had another name which caused the model not be found (even if the connectionstring was ok).